# Finding the data which builds a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi guys I've been halted in my tracks by a problem which I could use some help with. I'm trying to find the data source for one of the tables in my database, I've checked for extended properties and there aren't any.

I've managed to follow the trail back from the intermediate.view to the staging database but the trail just goes cold.

There are only two columns in the table (comments and ref_no). I've tried to use the following code to find other tables/views with the 'comments' column but nothing seems to fit;

```
USE [Database]
GO

SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME  LIKE 'comments'

ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME ASC
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's a "data source"? What are you even looking for? If you want to know where a table's data comes from, well, you can't, that's not tracked anywhere. Someone executed `INSERT` or `MERGE` statements at some point in time, that's all you can tell. If you suspect that's still happening now and again, set up a profiler or extended events trace for such statements.

Comment: By data source I simply mean the source of the data from which the table is built. 
I perfectly understand the fact that someone has executed an insert statement to create the table and I realise that it's bad practice to leave a table without any description of how.
My understanding of the other capabilities within management studio is limited so I was just enquiring.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming that it's possible the columns from the other table are not the same as the columns of the table you are trying to figure out how it gets populated, one suggestion is to search the staging DB for a value from the table and see if it's found anywhere. Might be a long way around, but could narrow down the tables that could be populating it

```
DECLARE @SearchStr NVARCHAR(100) = 'searchForThis'
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
 ColumnName NVARCHAR(370)
,ColumnValue NVARCHAR(3630)
)

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(256)
,@ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)
,@SearchStr2 NVARCHAR(110)
SET @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%' ,'''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = (SELECT    MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                      FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                      WHERE     TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)) ,
                                                   'IsMSShipped') = 0
                     )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL)
        AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName = (SELECT   MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                               FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                               WHERE    TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName ,2)
                                        AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName ,1)
                                        AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char' ,'varchar' ,'nchar' ,'nvarchar')
                                        AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
                              )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    INSERT  INTO @Results
                            EXEC
                                (
                                 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName
                                 + ', 3630) 
            FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' + ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                                )
                END
        END 
END

SELECT  ColumnName
   ,ColumnValue
FROM    @Results
```

Just need to change the `@SearchStr` value

EDIT:
This is how the results will be displayed if that value is found in the database. (I searched for the value `John`)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is entirely possible that whoever made it, over a year ago, has renamed the columns. So if I know for sure that a value appears in both tables I just have to replace the @SearchStr with the value.

Comment: @NHier1992 correct. Replace `searchForThis` with whatever value you want to look for, and the results will display in the `ColumnName` column as `Schema.TableName.ColumnName`

Comment: Awesome. I'll give it a go and let you know it it works. Thanks

Comment: Quick question before the weekend. Is this the expected result?

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: I'm assuming you were looking at the `messages`. If you click on the `Results` tab, that's were you will find the data if anything was found.

Comment: @NHier1992 added an image to my post on how it will look if the value is found

Comment: JUst because a value is in another table doesn't mean that it is the same or even related. This is very dangerous advice.

Comment: @HLGEM that is correct. I'm not saying that if it's found they should automatically assume that's the table. More research into that table will need to be done. This just might help in narrowing down tables.

Comment: HLGEM I understood @Doolius was giving me a good starting point in narrowing down my search. Thanks for updating with the image, unfortunately I'm only getting the previously posted message.

I'm having a long weekend so won't get a chance to test again until Tuesday, but thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Doolius awesome bit of script. Only just got round to testing this out today, worked perfectly.

Comment: @NHier1992 glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

If you have a staging table that the data comes from, then the data may have come from a data import. So look at the SSIS packages associated with your system or any data imports the application code runs.

If you currently have auditing (as all production databases should in my opinion), then look for the information in your audit tables.

If you don't have auditing and the data is changing, then instituting auditing on that table can help you identify the source because you will know what user put the data in and what datetime.

You might also look at whether there is a PK/FK relationship as there should probably be for anything named ref_no. That should tell you what tables this data is related to and might help you track down where it comes from. If you have no PK/FK relationships, then you will need to search the application code/ORM to find the relationships.

Incidentally, ref_no in another table is far more likely to find a useful match for you than comments. Comments columns are virtually never related because they are comments about the entity model in the table you are in. So you might have comments about the user or comments about a financial transaction. Those comments are not generally related to each other.

THe other way to find out is to ask people who have used the system for a long time, they may have more insight into where the data comes from.

Comment: thanks for the detailed advice but there is no SSIS package as the data is updated nightly with a single stored proc. I've already searched the proc but this table isn't one which is updated.

I'm 99% sure that it is the right table but it requires an update, without knowing where it came from I can't perform that update.